# Highcharts renders opposite y axis lower than chart's bottom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts renders title of opposite yAxis lower than chart's bottom.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u0yg5xj8/

I can't use `y` property of `yAxis.title` because I create title dynamically and don't know length of title. How place title correctly on the bottom of scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `align` and `textAlign` to get the axis title at the bottom of the opposite axis, facing away from the chart. For example:

```
yAxis: [{
    opposite: true,
    title: {
        align: 'low',
        textAlign: 'left',
        text: 'Second axis',
        rotation: 270
        // ...
    }
}]
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0yg5xj8/2/) of how it looks.